# What does Turbo Mode do?

Tags: tomena-sanner

In the 2009 WiiWare game *Tomena Sanner*, there is an option on the main menu for Turbo Mode. When I try to select it, every stage is locked with the message “Not available yet”.

What does Turbo Mode do? How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Nintendo Life](http://www.nintendolife.com/reviews/2010/01/tomena_sanner), Turbo Mode is a sped-up challenge mode unlocked after beating stage nine in Normal Mode.

> **After beating stage nine you'll unlock Endless Mode** (play through all stages consecutively - if you can!) **and Turbo Mode, which is a sped-up version of the game.** Beating all the stages in Turbo Mode will unlock an "endless" version of Turbo - nice to have when you're looking for that extra bit of challenge.
>
> <sub>[Review: Tomena Sanner - Nintendo Life](http://www.nintendolife.com/reviews/2010/01/tomena_sanner)</sub>